# Game Center displayed no data on iOS 10

Tags: swift, ios10, game-center

### Context

I have 2 games available on AppStore. On a device running iOS 9, Game Center View displayed data for LeaderBoards, Achievements and Challenges.

On another device running iOS 10 no data are displayed.

These apps are on AppStore for some times with no known problems. Going to iOS 10 lead to the loss of Game Center data.

### Code

Game Center view is displayed using `GKGameCenterViewController`.

### Game Center

I've checked Game Center data on iTunes Connect: everything is OK. It's also OK using Game Center app for Mac or Game Center app on iOS device running iOS 9.

### Tests

I ran test on a device running iOS 10, plugged to Xcode: everything was fine, with the same Game Center account.

Of course during all this tests this the same Game Center credentials is used.

#### iOS 9 — Simulator

[image]

#### iOS 9 — Device

[image]

#### iOS 10 — Simulator

[image]

#### iOS 10 — Device

[image]

*"Aucune donnée disponible"* is the french translation for *"No data available"*.

Comment: So GameCenter is running only on iOS 9?

Comment: @MarkBailey What other informations do you need?

Comment: @Domsware, just to confirm: the IOS10 device was previously confirmed to work properly on IOS9 (in French), is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a single device that previously worked on IOS9 and now isn't working on IOS10 even though other devices with the same ID work fine, we have to consider both server-side and client-side issues:

1. Server-side issue: We can't rule out server-side issues, especially given the other server-side issues that appear with GameCenter. In the past, for reasons that have never been explained by Apple, simply changing the default leaderboard has solved all sorts of game-center-won't-play-nice issues. Creating a new leaderboard and making it the default, or simply changing which leaderboard is default, seems to be sufficient. However, from my own experience, this works when the problem affects *all* users, not just 1 device.
2. Client-side issues: Since you're seeing different behaviors on different devices using a single game center ID, I believe it's more likely to be a client-side issue stemming from the upgrade process. I'd try two things.

First, log out of game center on the affected device, then log back in with a *different* game center ID. Does the problem still occur?

Second, log out of all three iTunes, iCloud and gameCenter (3 *separate* places in settings). Reboot the device, then log back in.

Admittedly, all of these are grasping at straws, but these items have corrected weird game center behaviors for me in the past.

Comment: Thank you! The second point worked: log out of all three iTunes, iCloud and gameCenter then reboot device.